# GIS/Gdal/OSGeos Import error in django on Windows

Tags: python, django, geospatial, postgis, geodjango

I am trying this from hours now and I couldn't get get it solved. I am using [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/gdal-importerror-in-python-on-windows) link to setup GeoDjango on Windows. I am getting following error message and I have no clue what to do. All the environment variables are set in Windows and I am able to import with

> from osgeo import gdal

successfully in python terminal as

> import gdal

is deprecated.
In Postgresql database I have all extensions available as required like **address_standardizer**, **fuzzystrmatch**, **ogr_fdw**, **pgrouting**, **plpgsql**, **pointcloud**, **pointcloud_postgis**, **postgis**, **postgis_sfcgal**, **postgis_tiger_geocoder** and **postgis_topology**.

Django Project Settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'postgis_24_sample',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Hello123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.postgis',
    ...
]
```

ERROR:

```
(easy_geodj) C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\easy_geodj\djlocate>python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x066D6330>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\aggregates.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import ExtentField
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collections import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\collections.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\easy_geodj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 48, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: have you set `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH`? are the GDAL DLLs on your windows path?

Comment: Yes i did added it

Comment: Please open `c:\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py` and add `print(self._name)` in a line before `self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)` and post results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GIS dependencies are really hard to get right, especially on Windows. If you want to stick with this OS I'd recommend keep using [OsGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).

The steps that worked for me are the following:

Make sure to uninstall every distribution of those GIS packages you've installed and carefully follow the [OSGeo4W installation instructions](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/#QuickStartforOSGeo4WUsers). Apache and MapServer are checked to be installed by default, you can uncheck them as they are not needed.

Than you can change your `settings.py` to look like this:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\geos_c.dll'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\gdal201.dll'
```

Note 1: the paths will depend on where you installed OSGeo4W but (as I remember) those are the defaults.

Note 2: if you download and install the 32-bit version your paths should look like this instead:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\geos_c.dll'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\gdal201.dll'
```

I've worked on a project using a similar stack and felt it was a lot easier to set things up on Linux (Ubuntu, particularly). If it's just a learning personal project or if it'll end up hosted on a Linux machine anyway, I'd suggest going for a Linux dev environment.

On Ubuntu, for example, you can just do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
```

The [GeoDjango official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/) have some good info too.

Answer (score 3):

I would ignore all attempts to manually handle the installation yourself, and use an [anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) environment.  GIS dependencies are notoriously fickle to install, and anaconda has smoothed a large number of rough edges.

Answer (score 0):

First type `python` ins cmd and check which version is installed. it shows a result as

`... [MSC v.1600 32 bit ..] ...`

well you can find that python is compiled with MSC compiler 32bit version 1600
using this link download `gdal` based on compiler

http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

for example you must download this version based on above python output

`MSVC 2010  win32   release-1600-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7`

download both `GDAL-2.2.3.win32-py3.4.msi` and `gdal-202-1600-core.msi` and install them.

Add these two variable into windows Environment

`` - `GDAL_DATA` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data`
- `path` = add this at the start `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\` ``

and finally add these to `setting.py`

`GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\geos_c.dll'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal202.dll'`